# JQgrid : Change entire row's font color if one column is filled

Tags: jqgrid, fonts, compiler-errors, jqgrid-formatter

I have read some post but I'm still can't follow due to i'm new in jqgrid.
I have a jqgrid which have 5 columns, but 1 column is empty for the beginning.
After do some update it would be filled.

I want JQgrid change the font color for this row, so if it is filled this row will be change the font color to blue.

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
....
colModel :[ 
        {name:'prob_id', index:'prob_id', hidden:true, width:10}, 
        {name:'Model',index:'Model',width:100,editable:true,search:true,stype:'text',searchoption:{sopt:['cn']}}, 
        {name:'Serial', index:'Serial',width:80,editable:true,search:true,stype:'text',searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']}},
        {name:'Lotno', index:'Lotno', width:50, editable:true,
                 search:true,
                 stype:'text',
                 searchoption:{sopt:['cn']}},
        {name:'Detail', index:'Detail', hidden:true,width:70,formatter:myformat}
                                        ],
....

function myformat ( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
                {
                        if (!empty(cellvalue)){
                        return '<font color="blue">' + cellvalue + '</font>';//or use classes
                        } else{
                        return '<font color="black">' + cellvalue + '</font>';//or use classes
                        }
                }
```

I would like to change the font color for all rows that have a value for the Detail Field

but I get an error:

```
empty is not defined
```

---

UPDATE

try this way :
I'm decided to move the condition to :

```
function myformat ( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
                {
                        if (cellvalue == "closed"){
                        return '<font color="blue">' + cellvalue + '</font>';//or use classes
                        } else{
                        return '<font color="black">' + cellvalue + '</font>';//or use classes
                        }
                }
```

and it works, but it seems just one column which turn to blue, I want entire row which have condition `CLOSED`.

Comment: try with this if (!null(cellvalue))

Comment: @Kvadiyatar: error, show : `object is not a function `

Comment: can u try with this one : if(cellvalue != Null)  ...plz let me know if still get error.

Comment: not show error but font color not change.

Comment: it's goes on if condition or else condition? ...you can check it by alert function...one should be in if & one alert should be on else conition...may be it's goes on else...so, as per that condition. you cant get font color.

Comment: Actually whats the need of if condition there ? If there is no value then the value wont be displayed so whats the need of font  color for the empty string.

Comment: If you are trying to give cell background color as per your condition then it has logic

Comment: If you still want to check, try this if(cellvalue != null && cellvalue !="")

Comment: I try to put alert in if first then show column's value, then add alert in else (alert show but value nothing).

Comment: See the answer (will change the entire row color based on condition ), Instead of detail==null || detail=="" check detail=="Closed" in the afterInsertRow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try afterInsertRow and setRowData like in the code given below

```
   afterInsertRow: function(rowid, rowData, rowelem) {
   var detail= rowData['Detail'];
   if(detail=="Closed"){
$(this).jqGrid('setRowData', rowid, false, { color: '#000' });
  }else {
$(this).jqGrid('setRowData', rowid, false, { color: '#FF0000' });
    }
    },
```

Remove gridView:true (afterInsertRow wont work if gridView is true)

Comment: where to put this? inside colModel or inside `jQuery("#list").jqGrid({` ?

Comment: Inside jQuery("#list").jqGrid({

Comment: color not change. Look at my updated post, It works but only for cell which have value `CLOSED`

Comment: then check detail=="Closed" in afterInsertRow method also

Comment: what are the expected values in Detail columns

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24679/discussion-between-nunu-and-kris)

Comment: for me I got solution from here http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/how-to-make-the-entire-row-bold